# Maven Repositories for Spring Roo

Tags: maven, maven-3, spring-roo, nexus

My intent is to proxy Roo Maven repository with my local Nexus installation, so that it will contain Roo 1.2.0.RELEASE packages.

On http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/resources.html it is written that Roo builds are published on http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release.

Unfortunately that link returns error **NoSuchKey**.

Is there some other Maven repository to get Roo packages from ?

Comment: Can you try using this mirror, specify spring-roo dependencies in your project and see if maven downloads it through your proxy?  The repository is not searchable and hence the message.

Comment: As a workaround, try locally installing the Roo libraries into your Maven repository. Often you don't find the Springsource libraries in the repositories that they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create (in Nexus) a proxy repository with the remote storage location = http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release
Then, add it to the public repositories group.

Comment: unfortunately this is what I wanted to do, but the repository returns error and is not indexed by Nexus

Answer (score 5):

Based on this [Nexus ticket](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-1121) I solved my problem by:

1. create Proxy on Nexus for http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release
2. add this repository into default "Public Repositories" group

Nexus will proxy requested artifacts and it will crate index of this artifacts, but it is not able to index the whole http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release repository, because its index is not published. The reason of this problem is that it is hosted on Amazon S3 storage.