# Can I be able to run my Spring roo project developed in STS with Roo version 1.3.1 in the latest version of Roo

Tags: spring, maven, java-8, spring-roo

We have developed a Spring roo project in STS with roo 1.3.1. I have now updated my STS to the latest version and installed roo 2.0.0 in it. When I try to import the existing roo project does not build successfully.

Can some one please tell me whether there is any compatibility issues with different versions of roo?

It was complaining about 2 dependency jars. So I added the below code.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.roo.wrapping/org.springframework.roo.wrapping.inflector -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.roo.wrapping</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.wrapping.inflector</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0.010</version>
</dependency>
```

the above dependency was not needed for older roo version.

Eventhough I added the above code it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to do that. Spring Roo 2.0 has changed all its architecture and there is no way to migrate a project from 1.3 to 2.0.

By example:

- Generated project in 2.0 is build on top Spring Boot
- Data access layer has been changed from Active Record pattern to Repository (using Spring Data)
- Default UI layer in 2.0 is based on Thymeleaft instead of JSP and tagx
- There is no support in 2.0 for Reverse Engineering feature

To see the differences just try to generated the `clinic.roo` script in both versions and compare the projects.

Comment: the clinic.roo does not work in 2.0.0... none of the examples start because the quoted inflector dependency disapeared from maven central or something...

Comment: try adding the mirrors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128779/maven-repositories-for-spring-roo